# How to make a contour map from a list of points and values?

Tags: qgis, cartography, contour, matplotlib

I need to create a nice map with contours that represent various thematic data on a scale of a country, for instance, average temperatures in Germany.

I have a list of coordinates with the values, and that's it. I am a bit lost here what's the best approach. The output should be a PDF or raster map (I am not interested in a web service). The base map can be very basic with just country borders and optionally major cities.

My idea was to use matplotlib and somehow overlay the contours over a map, but I don't think that it'd look professionally made and appealing.

What are your recommendations? Can QGIS do the complete job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the contour creation, see [How to create contour lines from point data using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112890/how-to-create-contour-lines-from-point-data)

You can add Natural Earth shapefile boundaries (or any other shaoefiles) as background, or Openstreetmap tiles via the Openlayers plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that the link provides guidelines for numeric values. The problem is that I also have different values (nominal), such as [good, very good, excellent], and dates. So not sure that QGIS can do it.

Comment: You can add an attribute field with scale-like index values from 1 to 3 for your three values to create a contour-like style. Another way would be Voronoi diagrams to collect points with the same value in one polygon.

Answer (score 0):

About a year ago i've been created a video how to make contour lines from points with qgis.

Available here: http://youtu.be/w4fEewn7gz0

Language: hungarian :D