# Making contour lines out of points with different heights using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, contour, depth

I have different points in a polygon. The points have the attribute "depth" and either have 0m, 2m or 4m depth. My task is now to create some sort of contour lines with the points with the same depth so that it is possible to see how deep the polygon is.

How can i do this?

I work with QGIS 2.4.

Comment: Like http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/112895/8673 ?